# Why is my tableView not taking up the full width?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the storyboard, my tableView looks like this (below the blue rectangle):

[image]

But when I run it it looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why that space is there on the right.

I constrained the image view to the left and right (I put 0 in the fields)
I also constrained the stackview inside the content view to the sides, and constrained the content view to the sides.

I tried constraining everything I could but it is still like this.

If anyone could let me know what I missed, that would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: First step is figuring out *what* is not sized as desired. Set a background color on your "main" view, a different background color for your scroll view, and a different background color for your cells. That should be a good starting point.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like the constraints are incorrect, check that the selected device for Storyboard is the same as the Emulator, maybe this is the reason why you see two different behaviours

Answer (score 0):

According to the selected cell, the width of your tableView is wrong - you need to setup constraints 0 to sides or width same as superView... It is not the cell